# How to best implement model delta (PUT/PATCH) in vue.js?

Tags: model, vue.js, vuejs2, delta

I have a POJO that I pass to a vue component - obviously, this object's values can be updated by vue's two-way data binding.

Having used backbone.js for a few years and having grown accustomed to models being instances of `Backbone.Model` that kept track of their changed properties, I have a hard time wrapping my head around how one would best implement a `toJSONDelta()`-like functionality (returning a copy of all changed properties of my vue component's data) "the vue way".

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use something like:

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: "#root",
        data: {
            a: 10,
            b: 20,
            c: {
                loveJS: true,
                vue: "isAwesome"
            }
        },
        methods: {
            track: (function(history){
                return function(n){
                    history.push(n)
                    console.log(history)
                }
            })([ /* history store */ ])
        },
        mounted: function(){
            this.$watch("$data", function(n){
                this.track( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(n)) ) // to remove watchers
            }, { deep: true, immediate: true});
        }
    })
```

Then, you can use something like [recursive-diff](https://github.com/cosmicanant/recursive-diff) to compare and generate diff between any two points in history or push the new object into something like [object-history](https://github.com/PolicyStat/object-history) which will then manage the history for you.